# Sql query that outputs last minute data

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

Good day everyone, I solve this problem. We need to display data on statuses 200 and 500 for the last minute from clickhouse to our grafana monitor.

I expect this request to work and output last minute data, but as soon as I enter it into the monitor on Grafana, it throws a "request error"

```
"100 - (sum(StatusRes != '200'[1m]) * 100),
 100 - (sum(StatusRes == '200'[1m]) * 100),"
```

Also tried like this:

```
SELECT
    $ timeSeries as t,
    StatusRes,
    sum (StatusRes == '200') * 100 / (StatusRes == '500'),
    Provider
FROM $ table

WHERE $ timeFilter

GROUP BY
    t,
    StatusRes,
    Provider
ORDER BY
    t,
    StatusRes,
    Provider
```

Comment: It's a grafana plugin error.

Comment: @Denny Crane, It turns out that if this is a bug of the grafana plugin, then the request for the number of requests for the last minute will not work?

Comment: I meant that the issue is not related to clickhouse. It's not a bug. You have misconfigured something. I have zero experience with grafana plugin.

Comment: @Dennu Crane, Yes, I understand that the error is not related to clickhouse, most likely the request itself is incorrect. But what should the correct "last minute query count" look like? I just took an example of a request from another source, and it's hard for me to understand how it should look like